# Jquery draggable div position

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

work sample : http://jsfiddle.net/murano55/bSPeC/2/

Why second div (2 .BOX) left position wrong ?
thanks.

Comment: What is it wrong about it? where do you want it to be positioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bSPeC/10/

Instead of using `ui.position.` inside the `drag` event, use `$(this).position().`

You will need to subtract the `#container` border yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to you offset() instead of position

http://jsfiddle.net/bSPeC/14/